# Exclude multiple folders (bash)

Tags: bash, shell

How to exclude more then one directory with find ?

exclude one folder

```
find * -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -not -name first_folder
```

Trying something like:

```
find * -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -not -name first_folder -or -not -name second_folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple `-not`s do work, just remove the `-or`.

```
find * -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0 -not -name first_folder -not -name second_folder
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I was following a tuturial blog :https://kaijento.github.io/2017/04/18/bash-mv-all-except/ which says you need to group things like. \( -not -name first_folder -or -not -name second_folder \) this did not work for me, bash just skipped it.